# Contingency Table from Sparse Matrix

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, contingency

I have a large sparse matrix. now I want to make contingency table of all combination of pair of columns.
For example : 
Let's say My sparse matrix is Mat

```
D1   D2  D3  D4  D5  ..  Dn
1    0   1   0   0   ..  0
0    1   1   1   1   ..  1
..   ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
1    0   1   0   1   ..  1
```

Now need to make contingency tables for all combination of Di and Dj for example Contingency table for **(D1,D2), (D1,D3), (D1,D4).. (D1, Dn), (D2,D3), (D2,D4) .. (D2,Dn) .. (Dn-1 , Dn)**

**structure of each Contingency Table**

```
 r1  r2
 r3  r4



#where r1 is total number of 1's in Di column 
#         r2 is total number of 1's in Di AND Dj column
#         r3 is total number of 1's in Di AND Dj column 
#         r4 is total number of 1's in Dj column
```

Also:

```
for each i in (1:n-1) {
    for each j in (i+1 : n) {
        Calculate r1,r2,r3,r4
        create contingency table for Ri and Rj
        apply fisher test on that 
    }
}
```

I want some fast implementation as it is taking more than 2-3 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one idea to get all the 2 x 2 matrices,

```
fun1 <- function(x,y){
 matrix(data = c(sum(m1[,x]), sum(m1[,c(x,y)]), sum(m1[,c(x,y)]), sum(m1[,y])), 
                                                               nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
 }
#where m1 is your original matrix

ind1 <- combn(1:ncol(m1),2)[1,]
ind2 <- combn(1:ncol(m1),2)[2,]
final.list <- Map(fun1, ind1, ind2)

head(final.list, 2)
#[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    3    6
#[2,]    6    3

#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    3    6
#[2,]    6    3
```

**DATA**

```
dput(m1)
structure(c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), .Dim = c(6L, 
6L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6"
)))
```

Or similarly,

```
fun2 <- function(x,y){
     matrix(data = c(c.sums[x], sum(c.sums[c(x,y)]), sum(c.sums[c(x,y)]), c.sums[y]),
                                                                    nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
 }

ind1 <- combn(1:ncol(m1),2)[1,]
ind2 <- combn(1:ncol(m1),2)[2,]
c.sums <- colSums(m1)

final.list2 <- Map(fun2, ind1, ind2)
```

Comment: Thanks. But still it is taking a lot of time. Dimension of Matrix is 8000 * 7000. Which means total C(7000,2) contingency tables. Initially table creation is very fast but after some time it becomes very slow and then finally get stuck.

Comment: 7000 columns??? and you think that means total of c(7000, 2)...? That will produce roughly 24.5 million tables!

Comment: Yes . That is why it is taking time.

Comment: Can Parallelism be applied here ? If so , please assist on this. for example parMapply etc

Comment: I am not familiar with Parallelism in R. I use spark for such tasks.